# Error installing Ansible Collection from Requirements file

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx, ansible-galaxy

I'm trying to install the cyberark.pas collection using a requirements file in my project.  Today I install the collection from AWX via ansible Galaxy, but the job fails a couple of times a day with the following error:

```
"stderr": "ERROR! Unexpected Exception, this is probably a bug: The read operation timed out",
```

Here is my requirements file:

```
---
collections:
  - name: cyberark.pas
    source: https://galaxy.ansible.com
```

After reading this ansible-galaxy timeout issue  https://github.com/ansible/galaxy/issues/2302 I thought I would change getting the collection from Github.  I found the collection here: https://github.com/cyberark/ansible-security-automation-collection and changed my requirements file to look like this:

```
---
collections:
  - name: https://github.com/cyberark/ansible-security-automation-collection.git
    type: git
```

When I run this from AWX I get the error that it is expecting a .tar file and this is not a .tar file.

I was hoping someone might be able to help me with what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I was able to install the collection without any problem with both versions of your `requirements.yml` file (ansible-core 2.14)

Comment: I don’t administer our AWX tower. Is there anything that might be configured there or do I need something I need configured in my project so it works for me?

Comment: We are experiencing similar issues with our pipelines, and this happens on and off, it goes away for a couple of weeks, then comes back. Looking for a way to mitigate it but it looks like a galaxy hosts issue.